# Добавление полей в настройках модуля

Tags: smarty, cs-cart

Как реализовать добавление полей по нажатию в настройках модуля?

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно использовать свой шаблон для настроек модуля. Для этого в addon.xml  используйте тип настройки template, а в default_value укажите название шаблона.

Полный путь до шаблона будет

themes/ТЕМА/addons/АДДОН/settings/ИМЯ_ШАБЛОНА